# Junit5/Jupiter - Print method names during maven build for

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

By default all class names of the unit tests are printed on the console. However I would like to include all methods/individual tests within the class to be printed on the console output when running maven verify.

My current output looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the class `KeyStoreUtilsShould` contains 35 individual tests which I would like to be printed one by one. It would also nice to have to see the execution time, which failed and which passed. The reason why I would like to see the individual tests is to easily inspect which tests are already included without digging the source code.

To reproduce:

- clone the project: https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart
- run `mvn clean verify`

Comment: Why do you really need that? If they ran successful what is the need for that? You might try this: https://github.com/fabriciorby/maven-surefire-junit5-tree-reporter for timing best use the simplest solution from the users guide: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks-before-after-execution

Comment: @khmarbaise I just also like verbose output and anyone can easily see all of the tests by just scanning the build output. It is also providing additional information for the ones who are interested without the need of digging the source code. By the way, your answer was the one which worked out for me. Would you like to provide a separate answer instead of a comment, so I could mark your answer as the one which I accepted. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment section khmarbaise dropped a link which worked out for me quite well. I requested him to promote it as an answer instead of a comment so I could mark it as resolved, however he didn't so I am posting his answer here.

I used https://github.com/fabriciorby/maven-surefire-junit5-tree-reporter plugin to generate more detailed output. It was previously like this:

[image]

And after using the plugin it became like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestWatcher` extension.

1. Create an extension class like below.

   ```java
   package com.seenukarthi.testutils.extensions;

   import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestWatcher;
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

   import java.util.Optional;

   public class TestsLogExtension implements TestWatcher {

       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("TestLogger");

       @Override
       public void testDisabled(ExtensionContext context, Optional<String> reason) {
           log.info("{}#{} is disabled because {}",
               context.getTestClass().orElse(Object.class),
               context.getDisplayName(), reason.orElse(""));
       }

       @Override
       public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext context) {
           log.info("{}#{} is Success",
               context.getTestClass().orElse(Object.class), context.getDisplayName());
       }

       @Override
       public void testAborted(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
           log.error("{}#{} is aborted",
               context.getTestClass().orElse(Object.class), context.getDisplayName(), cause);
       }

       @Override
       public void testFailed(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
           log.error("{}#{} is failed",
               context.getTestClass().orElse(Object.class), context.getDisplayName());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the extension in your test classes like the one below.

   ```java
   package com.seenukarthi.test;

   import com.seenukarthi.testutils.extensions.TestsLogExtension;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
   import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

   @ExtendWith({TestsLogExtension.class})
   class BeanTest {
       @Test
       void init() {
           //Your test case.
       }
   }
   ```

This will print the method tested with the results.